# Find matching objects in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to iterate through an array and find matching attributes within objects. For example:

```
<SockDrawer:0x007f834c9a49b8 @socks=[#<Sock:0x007f834c9a4cd8 @brand="Nike", @style="quarter", @color="white">, #<Sock:0x007f834c9a4c10 @brand="Nike", @style="quarter", @color="black">, #<Sock:0x007f834c9a4af8 @brand="Nike", @style="quarter", @color="red">, #<Sock:0x007f834c9a4a30 @brand="Nike", @style="quarter", @color="white">]
```

So we can see that my `@socks` array has two socks that match. I am trying to write a method to find the matching attributes so I can pull out the two white socks and wear them.

My thought process was to somehow start with the first object and compare it to the rest of the objects (iterating through the array to find a match.)

Comment: Do you want to _search_ for a specific attribute (like "white") or just retrieve generally all matching pairs for a given attribute, like return 2 white socks and two red (if you had a second red)

Comment: Looking to have all attributes match. Compare brand, color, length.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have the beginnings of a question, but what is a minimal example of the code you've written toward solving this, or where have you searched and what didn't you understand about what you read? As is it looks like you're asking us to write code for what should be a very simple problem. Also, rather than show an inspection of the array, instead provide a clear-text, source-definition of the array, or a minimal definition of the object along with the initializer for the array. That helps us help you and helps others looking for a similar answer.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to redefine the [`#==`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-3D-3D) on a `Sock`:

```
class Sock
  def ==(other_sock)
    brand == other_sock.brand && style == other_sock.style
  end
end
```

By default, [`#==`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-3D-3D) on all Ruby object returns true if two objects are the same:

```
a = Object.new # => #<Object:0x0000000128df60>
a.__id__ # => 9727920
b = Object.new # => #<Object:0x00000001289cd0>
b.__id__  # => 9719400
a == a # => true
a == b # => false
```

Fun fact: objects from some built-in classes like integers are reused as an optimization.

```
Object.new.__id__ == Object.new.__id__ # => false
(2 * 8).__id__ == (4 * 4).__id__ # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @faraz answer, you can select the matching sock by using [`Enumerable#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) on the collection:

```
sock = @socks.first # your desired sock
other_sock =  @socks.find {|sock| sock == @sock }
```